# Why did changing username result in downvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

I ended up doing a social experiment (unintentionally) on Stack Overflow to test its diversity and if any story of it having unfair practices were correct.

I asked an irrelevant question (CAD) question from my user account 1. I was immediately notified that it was an irrelevant question as CAD is not a programming topic. We still have to give some command in command line for which I felt it qualified for a technical question. However, I understand that it is not a programming question and should have not been asked.

That question remained open for 30 days - I did not receive a single downvote. Then I merged my two accounts yesterday and I immediately got 3 downvotes. I agree with those.

How did just changing username drew downvotes? Did changing the username to my own personal name had anything to contribute to it? If my question was of poor quality (which I completely agree with), what were moderators doing in 30 days when the question was left open?

Comment: Well, that was not exactly a test with sufficient data to draw a reliable conclusion.  The number of SO users that still use their free time to contribute answers and moderate content are quite overwhelmed with the question volume.  Not subtle either, the balance is off by a factor of 2.  That inevitably leaves a *lot* of questions that never get any attention.  It is random.

Comment: 30 days VS 2 days? so for 1st 30 days moderatos were "over-whelmed" but suddenly they found out time?

Comment: Please lookup the definition of the word "random" in an English dictionary.

Comment: Or the question was bumped, so it attracted new activity, with downvotes?

Comment: One instance of something is an anecdote, not an experiment.

Comment: The users moderatoring were out having fun? I know, incredible.

Comment: "I ended up doing a social experiment (_unintentionally_) to test..." -> wait, how can you do experiments _unintentionally_??

Answer (score 18):

Your interpretation of the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41588509/timeline) is incorrect.

[image]

You picked up a down vote on Jan, 11th, the day you posted. It entered the close vote queue but that flag aged away after 4 days. On Jan, 22th it entered the Close Vote queue for the second time. It was edited for tags on Jan, 28th and that user also close voted. At Feb, 7th the close review task was complete while either one of the last close voters or a regular visitor also down voted the question.

The last down vote was casted today, probably because of the meta effect. Do notice that over the existence of that question it was viewed 33 times.

The system works as intended. Keep in mind that some tags, like AutoCad, have a low number of followers. It might take awhile until the community get to it. On the plus side, those low traffic tag followers are in general very quality minded. They down vote more easily.

Comment: Question had same tags throughout. I never changed them. And why did all the activities suddenly jumped high after merging my two accounts? For 28 days, are you telling me that entire forum moderation was low on activity?

Comment: @KhushbooSingh no, it did not had the same tags throughout. It had photoshop and autocad until Jan,28. After that only autocad. Your question saw a normal attention span over the period, entering triage, first post and the close vote queue a couple of times. The tag edit on jan ,28 bumped it on the active list. There is no sudden change in activity.

Comment: going by your statement -  there was a tag change (Which I suppose I had not done), on 28th. That should have increased it's traffic on that day or week. From 28th to 11th , you still have 13 days. Even If you say it attracted a downvote on the same day, it should have attracted downvotes on the day its tags were edited - On 28th, or may be for a week after after that. But when I merged my account yesterday, how did it jump to 2 more downvotes (infact 6 more, which after moderation went to 3 downvotes)? Activity for this post 1st got edited on 28th - what happened between 28th Jan to 9th Feb?

Comment: Why merging 2 accounts suddenly increased activity for this post but changing tags would not have? Because tags got changed under a different user name and not with my own user name?

Comment: the merging of your account has nothing to do with what happened on that question. You're assuming causality where there is none, it is *random*, with a normal track record (which was already indicated by Hans Passant)

Comment: I would be happy to believe what you are saying. I just want to bring this to attention of moderators not everybody. SInce there is no way to clarify things with moderators, i can only do it with a post. I hope its understood that I do not have any negative motivation to ask this question but rather to bring it to moderators' attention that there probably is a bleak possibility of bullying happening here and may be I just need help and I am not scared to ask for it. I do not mean to attract any negative attention. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Votes are meant to balance over time.... It is intended. You did this ONCE. You can't talk about stuff like bullying for downvotes on a bad question @Khushboo. The timing is random, not related to your account merge. A bad question got downvotes. That is the system working. Did someone post an insulting comment or imply anything about your race directly? No?... Then it isn't bullying. It's moderation

Comment: @Patrice - as i said Patrice - I am nowhere offended with downvotes. I had mentioned in my post that downvotes is not what I am questioning. It's the timeline of it.

Comment: @Khushboo but the timeline is inconsequential. That is what you seem not to be getting. Your post gathered few views over 30 days. Some of these views gave you downvotes. An edit on your question popped it back on top of the active queue, as well as some close vote queue activity. Your account name merging is COMPLETELY irrelevant to those downvotes. Anyway you say those 3 downvotes came IMMEDIATELY after a merge and that your question had no downvotes before. This isn't even what happened, as the timeline proves.

Comment: Seems to me you have a preconceived notion that SO users are racist or sometthing and are looking for proof. That is called confirmation bias.

Comment: @Patrcie - Why are you just not getting that if i would have got those downvotes even after it's 1st edit - on 28th, I wouldnt have had any issues. It is only after merge - on 10th, that it started getting downvotes? Your explanation to it is that it is co-incidence or random. Fine, I am trying to think that way. And proving SO moderators wrong - is a very broad category you are talking about. Many of these SO moderators have helped me learn a lot from programming. It's their answers that has helped me learn EVEN when they downvote or close a qquestion. But sometimes, this is just not the case

Comment: @khushboo the first downvote you got on the day the questoonwas asked.... Way before the merge.

Comment: @rene in the question itself the OP says that "any stories of unfair practices". I am sorry but that is how I read that and the consequent reaction to 3 warranted downvotes on a bad question... Maybe I'm being too cynical but it looks like barn shooting.

Comment: ok, I appreciate that downvote. Do you know there are additional 5 downvotes, right after merge? out of which 2 downvotes were not accepted for some reason. So in total 3.

Comment: @Patrice OK, fair enough. I just don't want to go down that path ...

Comment: @khushboo not accepted downvotes?.... What? I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @KhushbooSingh maybe you should update your question how you perceive the timeline of all events, including when you merged accounts and when questions were asked and votes came in because it looks like you are talking about way different things then I am.

Comment: @Patrice - moderators have the privilege to go through the entire history of post - along with votes. My question is for moderators, i never intended it for everybody. I do not think there is a way to ask moderators only, or post something only to their visibility. So explain - the 2 down-votes may be, which you probably do understand?

Comment: @rene - just so that you know, I did  not decide on question's subject. It was edited by a moderator - so subject of this question is given by moderator, not me.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh You may need to clarify who you mean when you say  "moderators" in this case? Regular non-moderator users can also downvote, close and vote to delete questions. Also, rene is not a moderator either and your question never got edited by a moderator.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh your question was edited because it contained noise that didn't help your question. Please [edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/343545/edit) your question to include the detail that are lacking to address the concern you have.

Comment: @khushboo but the mods can't see why people voted. What do you expect here? It's not like mods have a mind reading machine that says why people voted... Anyway yes it is possible these 2 downvotes were casted bbecause of your username. It's also downvotes on a bad question, so nothing to worry about. You worry about the timeline of it all but : 1) the timeline doesn't matter... 2) 1 of the 3 downvotes isn't even casted when you say, so 33% of your argument is wrong.... 3) it's what is supposed to happen on a bad question.... If it was a good Q getting downvoted,maybe. Not what we see here

Comment: @rene - did I once say or ask why my question was edited? I agree to the edits made. Why any qualms on that. I just said that the subject of this question was moderator given and not my own - this was in reply to a suggestion made in comment asking me to edit a question which was already edited by moderators.

Comment: @Patrice thank you Patrice for agreeing that 67% of my argument was right. I would not have even posted it to bring any negative attention to forum, if I had the privilege of posting it to visibility of moderators only. there are few things which only moderators needs to see and not the entire forum, like complains or doubts.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh you can flag your own question and post a link to this meta post and ask the diamond moderators to have a look with whatever your concern is.

Comment: @khushboo for which you have custom flags btw. And 67% of your argument MAY be right. Doesn't mean it is. 2 downvotes is hardly a case woeth bringing up. ESPECIALLY on a bad question. Sincerely what do you hope moderators can do? It is a bad question. They can't know why people voted. All they will see is votes cast on a bad question and say 'yup.. That is how the system works'

Comment: @Patrice - ok, i agree. But what does a user do when they feel (with proof) that they are being bullied? Is there any way to not post it on forum (its not a technical question that needs everybody's attention) and post it only to moderator's visibility? If not, then, posts like this will be misunderstood.

Comment: @Khushboo it is TWO downvotes on a bad post. YOU ARE NOT BEING BULLIED. for crying out loud... You posted a bad question, it got downvoted. Downvotes aren't against you. They are on your content. And again if you have concerns, flag your question with a custom flag. That will go to moderators. But again what would you expect of such a flag? The questoon is off topic. They won't invalidate the downvotes, since they can't know why it was posted. Answer this : what do you expect moderators to do about two downvotes on a bad question that we have no real proof were wrongly casted?

Comment: @KhushbooSingh Both comments above your last one literally told you how to do it: Flag your question, use the custom flag reason and describe the problem. Only moderators get to see that.

Comment: Circumstancial evidence doesn't count as proof btew, so you can't say the timeline is a proof of that...

Comment: @Patrice - once again - its not about downvotes. I am sure you understand that by now. And I am trying to digest what you said - that timeline of it was purely coincidental. I will go by that. thanks.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh Also don't forget about the fact that you have four questions, two of which have no downvotes at all and one upvote each. Don't you think that if people were really "racist" or "fascist" (as you state in the [original version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/343545/1) of this question) they would have downvoted more than just the one bad and off-topic question of yours?

Comment: @Keiwan for nth time now - its not about downvotes. And I sure faced few things in forum because of which I post it here today. It's not just this question alone.

Comment: @khushboo then add those other "few things" to your question. And yes it is because of downvotes. You say it isn't and you say it is because of the motivation behind those downvotes. But you sincerely cannot know the motivation. You are GUESSING a motivation and being offended by what you guess. You cannot know for sure. So you cannot get offended for sure. You have real proof besides timing as to the fact these votes were racist?please offer it. That will make a way more compelling argument and my (and I am willing to bet rene's too) stance will change 100%

Comment: @KhushbooSingh There are no suspicious downvotes on your question, and you've continually ignored the fact that two out of the three total downvotes occurred *before* the account merge. You received one downvoted on Jan 11, one on Feb 7 and one on Feb 11. Your account merge occurred on Feb 10, *after* two downvotes had already been cast on the question. There is no pattern here, and the votes have nothing to do with your name change.

Comment: @meagar - ok, my bad then. I thought it was downvoted yesterday because that is when I noticed those downvotes. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @meager not able to delete question. any ways i can? thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to delete it? It is a valid concern and it has a great answer. Deleting your question would delete value.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh it's great you decided to bring this up, rather than say nothing and walk away and forever have your experience here tinted by the sense that the community is widely prejudiced against users based on their name, race, assumed place of origin, etc. This is a useful discussion to keep around. Don't mind the downvotes - they're most likely to express disagreement with your premise; they will not affect your reputation count in any way.